# Get Short Message from PduRequest

Tags: java, sms, smpp

I'm using [cloudhopper-smpp](https://github.com/twitter/cloudhopper-smpp) for receiving SMS over SMPP. After having implemented a `DefaultSmppSessionHandler`, PDU-Requests are being received by the SessionHandler (in the overridden `firePduRequestReceived` method).

Are there any helper-classes/Utils to extract SMS from `PduRequest`'s of type `deliver_sm`?
Couldn't find any getters in `PduRequest` to access the SMS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer.

```
        if (pduRequest.getCommandId() == SmppConstants.CMD_ID_DELIVER_SM) {
         DeliverSm mo = (DeliverSm) pduRequest;
         int length = mo.getShortMessageLength();
         Address source_address = mo.getSourceAddress();
         Address dest_address = mo.getDestAddress();
         byte[] shortMessage = mo.getShortMessage();
         String SMS= new String(shortMessage);
        }
```